# Slow Reputation Calculation?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm very new to the stackoverflow community, so I apologize if this is a duplicate or inappropriate question (I tried to search for answers beforehand but couldn't find them).

I noticed that, on stackoverflow.com, I have 4 up votes on one question and 1 up vote on another, but my reputation is only 43. Is this because I have sustained some kind of penalty I am not aware of? Or does the reputation just take time to calculate sometimes?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/130427/credford

---

#### Update

So it looks like the fact that I edited the Trace Table question more than 6 times caused it to become CW, negating any reputation I might receive on up-votes to it. I'll be sure not to do this in the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one question became [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow) after the last edit, so you no longer get rep for up-votes on it.

Comment: Damn. Than kind of sucks. I was really counting on that question generating some reputation for me, which is one reason I took the time to edit it so many times. Ironically, it looks like that continual editing what made it CW. I'll be sure to keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @credford: Once bitten, twice shy. So if it's still ain't perfect after the 5th edit, leave it. Use commenting as footnote :)

Comment: ...and then have some others merge the comments into the question after all, hence still hitting that 6 edits. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question [Trace Table for Python Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645028/trace-table-for-python-programs) became [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow), so it could be that you gained 1 upvote after that point. And CW does not award reputation.